# Problem with SvnInfo in MSBuild (using MSBuildCommunityTasks)

Tags: svn, msbuildcommunitytasks

I have a script, that I will use together with cc.net. But for now I'm facing a problem with the RepositoryPath attribute. The following script (extract of the sample script from MSBuildCommunityTask) is giving me troubles:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
     ToolsVersion ="3.5">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" />

  <Target Name="RemoteInfo">
    <SvnInfo RepositoryPath="http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/svn/msbuildtasks/trunk/Master.proj">
      <Output TaskParameter="RepositoryPath" PropertyName="RepositoryPath" />
      <Output TaskParameter="RepositoryRoot" PropertyName="RepositoryRoot" />
      <Output TaskParameter="LastChangedAuthor" PropertyName="LastChangedAuthor" />
      <Output TaskParameter="LastChangedRevision" PropertyName="LastChangedRevision" />
      <Output TaskParameter="LastChangedDate" PropertyName="LastChangedDate" />
      <Output TaskParameter="Schedule" PropertyName="Schedule" />
      <Output TaskParameter="NodeKind" PropertyName="NodeKind" />
      <Output TaskParameter="RepositoryUuid" PropertyName="RepositoryUuid" />
   </SvnInfo>
   <Message Text="RepositoryRoot: $(RepositoryRoot)" />
   <Message Text="RepositoryPath: $(RepositoryPath)" />
   <Message Text="LastChangedAuthor: $(LastChangedAuthor)" />
   <Message Text="LastChangedRevision: $(LastChangedRevision)" />
   <Message Text="LastChangedDate: $(LastChangedDate)" />
   <Message Text="Schedule: $(Schedule)" />
   <Message Text="NodeKind: $(NodeKind)" />
   <Message Text="RepositoryUuid: $(RepositoryUuid)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Command line:

```
D:\Test>msbuild test.build /target:RemoteInfo
```

The answer is:

```
D:\_SolutionTrunk\build\test.build(7,2): error MSB6001: Ungültiger Befehlszeilenschalter für "svn.exe". Illegales Zeichen im Pfad.
```

Which can be translated as: *Invalid commandline switch for "svn.exe". Illegals Character in path.*

Of course actually I'll use the for my script the *SvnCheckout* Task with a *RepositoryPath="https://mySvnServer.myIntranet.myDomain:8443/svn/repository/someName/trunk*

I'm always facing the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved!

When using any Subversion Task in *MSBuildCommunityTask*, the location for the command-line Subversion (svn.exe) is been looked-up in the *PATH*-Variable.
On my computer was an illegal Character ("). This throws an exception, which says, there is an illegal character in the path...
I misunderstood the error, I thought the illegal character was in the *RepositoryPath*-Attribute.

Comment: I also had this issue and it was the same thing.. mystery solved.